# I am this Error In Graphql "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: laravel, graphql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKxu5.png)

I am trying to create an Api in Laravel using Graphql but i am getting this error "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" Please help me with this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

If you use GraphQL through sessions(Laravel sanctum) and CSRF, add the following to the  in the published view:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Modify the Playground config:

```
GraphQLPlayground.init(root, {
  endpoint: "{{url(config('graphql-playground.endpoint'))}}",
  settings: {
    'request.credentials': 'same-origin',
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrftoken"]').content
  }
})
```

and make sure uncommented this line in `config/graphql-playground.php` :

```
'middleware' => ['web']
```